# DataGridView deleting row save

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

my problem is that i have datagridview, and i select row i click delete button but when i refresh it is back

```
Private Sub btnDlt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDlt.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgwData.SelectedRows
        dgwData.Rows.Remove(row)
        SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
    Next
End Sub
```

and my upadte is working good, it is saving everything, here is code

```
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    If MsgBox("Nazaj si prajete uložiť tieto zmeny?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        SQL.DBDA.Update(SQL.DBDT)
        loadGrid()
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        If SQL.hasException() Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        btnUpdate.Enabled = False
        loadGrid()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Put your cursor on `Remove` and press F1.  `Remove` is different than `Delete`.  And if you are using a DataAdapter and a DataSource you should be working on them, not DGV rows.

Comment: can you post example how it should looks?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be with your datasource, check your delete query if it work fine.